# Error: "object.median is not a function" - MSAVI index calculation in Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to calculate MSAVI index in Google Earth Engine but the following error occurs:

> MSAVI.median is not a function

What can I do to fix this?

[Code Editor script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/e8ee9e0bb417cf34ee907287dea960e6)

```
var Samarkand = ee.FeatureCollection("users/xodjayevshovkat/Samarkand");
var S2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')


.filterDate('2018-01-01','2018-10-01')
.filterBounds(Samarkand)
.filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 60);


var maskcloud1 = function(image) {
var QA60 = image.select(['QA60']);
return image.updateMask(QA60.lt(1));
};


var MSAVI = function(image) {
  var img = image.expression(
  '(2 * NIR + 1 - sqrt(pow((2 * NIR + 1), 2) - 8 * (NIR - RED)) ) / 2', 
  {
    'NIR': image.select('B8'), 
    'RED': image.select('B4'), 
});
};

var MSAVImed = MSAVI.median();

var MSAVI_pal = ['#d73027', '#f46d43', '#fdae61', '#fee08b', '#d9ef8b',
'#a6d96a'];



var plotMSAVI = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(S2.select(['MSAVI']), Samarkand, ee.Reducer.mean(), 500,'system:time_start', 'system:index')
          .setChartType('LineChart').setOptions({
                title: 'MSAVI Samarkand 2018',
                hAxis: {title: 'Date'},
                vAxis: {title: 'MSAVI'},
});

print(plotMSAVI);

Map.addLayer(MSAVImed.clip(Samarkand), {min: -0.5, max: 0.9, palette: MSAVI_pal}, 'MSAVI');
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, and thank you for taking the Tour. I took the liberty of converting your "Wall of code" post into something that won't attract as many downvotes, but you still need to [Edit] the question to specify the exact software in use and the line of code  where the error is generated.

Comment: Hi! Please see the [guide on posting Earth Engine questions](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/help#gis-stack-exchange). It's important to make sure your script is reproducible. That means you either need to share all assets used in your script or mock up an example that reproduces the issue. Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MSAVI` variable is a function, but you are calling the `ee.ImageCollection.median()` method on it, which is why you get the error (i.e., your function has no `median()` method). You need to apply the `MSAVI` function to the `S2` collection and then call `.median()` on it. I've edited your script to do this and also apply the cloud mask function.

Note that I've mocked up a feature collection since your asset is not shared publicly (you'll need to redefine your asset).

[Code Editor script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/20af6e9fe523f0420b3cfd2ad338f0b4)

```js
// Define a geometry.
var geometry = ee.Geometry.MultiPolygon(
  [[[[-113.04179687499999, 42.7991879605782],
     [-113.04179687499999, 41.56178373305603],
     [-110.75664062499999, 41.56178373305603],
     [-110.75664062499999, 42.7991879605782]]],
   [[[-111.45976562499999, 41.955158501392994],
     [-111.45976562499999, 40.96720543432847],
     [-109.87773437499999, 40.96720543432847],
     [-109.87773437499999, 41.955158501392994]]]], null, false);

// Make the geometry a feature collection.
var Samarkand = ee.FeatureCollection(geometry);

// Import S2 image collection.
var S2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
  // Filter collection.
  .filterDate('2018-01-01','2018-10-01')
  .filterBounds(Samarkand)
  .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 60);

// Define a cloud masking function.
var maskcloud1 = function(image) {
  var QA60 = image.select(['QA60']);
  return image.updateMask(QA60.lt(1));
};

// Define an index function (return only MSAVI).
var MSAVI = function(image) {
  return image.expression(
    '(2 * NIR + 1 - sqrt(pow((2 * NIR + 1), 2) - 8 * (NIR - RED)) ) / 2', 
    {
      'NIR': image.select('B8'), 
      'RED': image.select('B4'), 
    }).rename('MSAVI').copyProperties(image, image.propertyNames());
};

// Apply the cloud mask function.
var MSAVIcol = S2.map(maskcloud1)
 // Apply the MSAVI transformation.
 .map(MSAVI);

// Calculate the per-pixel median MSAVI for all images in collection.
var MSAVImed = MSAVIcol.median();

// Define vis params.
var MSAVIvis = {
  palette: ['#d73027', '#f46d43', '#fdae61', '#fee08b', '#d9ef8b', '#a6d96a'],
  min: -0.5,
  max: 0.9};

// Plot a time series of 
var plotMSAVI = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
  imageCollection:MSAVIcol,
  regions: Samarkand,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 1000,
  xProperty: 'system:time_start',
  seriesProperty: 'system:index'})
  .setChartType('LineChart').setOptions({
    title: 'MSAVI Samarkand 2018',
    hAxis: {title: 'Date'},
    vAxis: {title: 'MSAVI'},
});

// Display the results.
print(plotMSAVI);
Map.addLayer(MSAVImed.clipToCollection(Samarkand), MSAVIvis, 'MSAVI');
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Justin